# Finding number of users in each 15 minutes interval continuously for 6 years in hive

Tags: hive

I have more than 100k users. Each user starts using their phone at different timestamp value and ends by different timestamp.

I want to know for each 15 minutes interval how many users are using their phone

Attached the sample input and required output format.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Hi, can you please tell us what have you tried so far to achieve your goal?

Comment: Hi have created the interval table and joined the data table  the actual data table is huge so the running time and loading time is to high so looking for other options